# The parameterized query

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I keep getting this error message when I try to run a page..

> The parameterized query '(@Medication nvarchar(14),@Quantity nvarchar(9),@RequestedDate n' expects the parameter '@RequestedDate', which was not supplied.

This is my code-behind file:

```vb
Dim conn As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand

'Getting today's date to store into database to let staff know when prescription was ordered
'reference for this code : - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx

Dim thisDay As DateTime = DateTime.Today
Session("DateRequested") = (thisDay.ToString())
Dim Medication As String
Dim Quantity As String
Dim RequestedDate As String
Dim Pharmacy As String
Dim PatientNumber As String

Medication = txtDrug1.Text + " " + txtDrug2.Text + " " + txtDrug3.Text + " " + txtDrug4.Text + " " + txtDrug5.Text
Quantity = txtQuant1.Text + " " + txtQuant2.Text + " " + txtQuant3.Text + " " + txtQuant4.Text + " " + txtQuant5.Text

RequestedDate = Session("Date Requested")
PatientNumber = Session("PatientNumber")
Pharmacy = txtPharmacy.Text

Dim cmdstring As String = "INSERT INTO Prescription (Medication, QntyandStrength, RequestedDate, Pharmacy, PatientNumber) Values (@Medication, @Quantity, @RequestedDate, @Pharmacy, @PatientNumber)"

conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\myAppointments\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, conn)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medication", Medication)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Quantity)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestedDate", RequestedDate)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pharmacy", Pharmacy)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientNumber", PatientNumber)

conn.Open()

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()

MsgBox("Your Prescription Has Been Requested!")
```

And the Database types are:

```sql
[PrescriptionNumber] INT          NOT NULL,
[Medication]         NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
[QntyandStrength]    NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
[RequestedDate]      NVARCHAR(70) NULL,
[Pharmacy]           VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[PatientNumber]      CHAR (10)    NULL,
```

Any advice on how to change this?

Comment: Why are you storing a date as a string?

Comment: Use `.Add` aswell instead of `.AddWithValue`

Comment: Are you certain that on this line `RequestedDate = Session("Date Requested")` that `RequestedDate` has an _actual_ value instead of `Nothing`?

Comment: I'm assuming it does from the variable I declared that assigns today's date to it

Comment: It hasn't fully shown the date variable declare

Comment: Have you confirmed that those variables are in your session?

Comment: When you assign today's date, you use `Session("DateRequested")` but when you later retrieve it you use `Session("Date Requested")` (note space between words).  Are you certain that `RequestedDate` is not Nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to the session variable is incorrect as Chris Dunaway has pointed out.

You declare the variable and assign the value:

```
Session("DateRequested") = (thisDay.ToString())
```

...but then you refer to it with a different name...

```
RequestedDate = Session("Date Requested")  ''This variable name has a space.
```

So, when you pass the parameter...

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestedDate", RequestedDate)
```

...you're passing a reference to a null object.  There is no Session("Date Requested").

Comment: Hey everyone, yes mistake with my silly eyes there was space in session, it finally works, thanks for help!